# Multiple Mutually Exclusive JWPlayers

Tags: html, wordpress, jwplayer

Trying to setup Multiple Mutually Exclusive JWPlayers v8.1. I keep getting the 1st video listed and it takes up almost the whole page. As can be seen in the code I'm trying to set the video height to 200 and the width to 300.
Here is the code I'm using:
Edit: Trying to have these appear on the page beside each other.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/players/oytB1cN5-9X6UI8lV.js"></script>
                <title>Multiple Mutually Exclusive JWPlayers</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#EEE">
            <div id="container"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container").setup({
            file: [jwplayer oytB1cN5        
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            stretching: "none",
            events:{
                onPlay: function() {
                jwplayer('container2').stop();jwplayer('container3').stop();
                },
                onTime: function(object) {
                if(object.position > object.duration - 1) {this.pause();}
                }
            }
            });
            </script>
            <br />
            <div id="container2"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container2").setup({
            file: [jwplayer 2kd1G7dT            
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            stretching: "none",
            events:{
                onPlay: function() {
                jwplayer('container').stop();jwplayer('container3').stop();
                },
                onTime: function(object) {
                if(object.position > object.duration - 1) {this.pause();}
                }
            }
            });
            </script>
            <br />
            <div id="container3"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container3").setup({
            file: [jwplayer GuoewKQp-Qz7uhmTV           
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            stretching: "none",
            events:{
                onPlay: function() {
                jwplayer('container').stop();jwplayer('container2').stop();
                },
                onTime: function(object) {
                if(object.position > object.duration - 1) {this.pause();}
                }
            }
            });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a style tag inside each div and set the width there using CSS.